# How to change an existing variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, replace

```
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you want to choose rock, paper, or scissors?")
var computerChoice = Math.random()
if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
    computerChoice("Rock");
} else if (computerChoice >= 0.67) {
    computerChoice("Scissors");
} else {
    computerChoice("Paper");
}
```

I am new to the website and coding in general.  I was trying to create a simple rock, paper, scissors game and forgot how I would change the computerChoice variable to either a.Rock, b.Scissors, or c. paper?

Comment: It is also giving me "TypeError: number is not a function

Comment: computerChoice("Rock") would be calling a function called computerChoice and passing it a parameter "Rock".  You already set the variable once with `computerChoice = Math.random()`.  Why would you think the syntax to change it would be any different?

Answer (score 3):

```
computerChoice("Scissors");
```

Should be

```
computerChoice="Scissors";
```

That's how you assign something to a variable. The format you are using is used for calling a function.

You have already used the correct syntax for an assignment in your code in first few lines

```
var computerChoice = Math.random()
```

That is how it goes, just that if you want to assign a new value you just don't declare it with a `var`

Declaration syntax:

```
var variableName = Value   // if Value is a string, it goes inside quotes
```

Assign a new value

```
variableName = NewValue   // if NewValue is a string, it goes inside quotes
```